# Replace column in a dataframe with another column based on index

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe **A**:

```
        score   content  content_preprocessed   for_analysis
1         5       a             aaa                 True
2         5       b             NaN                 False
3         1       c             ccc                 True
4         1       d             ddd                 True
```

I need to replace `content_preprocessed` column with the following new column from dataframe **B**:

```
        content_preprocessed
1              aaz  
3              ccf     
4              ddo
```

which contains new values for `content_preprocessed` where `for_analysis` is set to `True`. The values for `content_preprocessed` should remain `NaN` if the corresponding `for_analysis` is `False`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
A.loc[A.for_analysis & (A.index.isin(B.index)) , content_preprocessed] = B.content_preprocessed
```